# Authorize.net not working after ssl installed in wordpress site

Tags: php, ssl, wordpress, authorize.net

We have a project developed in wordpress. This had a payment method working. We recently added SSL to the server. Since that time, the authorize.net is not working. It just refresh the page and goes nowhere. We checked the error log and getting "User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values." error message. 
I want to know
Do we need to generate new transaction id and app id after adding SSL in our server ?
Do we need to update the authorize.net settings after adding SSL in our server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update Authorize.NET's settings for your website. At the very least, you would have to include an https:// url (it is probably currently configured with http:// url)

Comment: Thanks Adam,Can you please let me know what settings I will need to update in authorize.net account ?

Comment: I've used many payment gateways...but not Authorize. It shouldn't be too hard to find & figure out. I based my answer on my experience with all the others being basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you obtained a certificate using the SHA2 encryption, this may be the cause.  See [this thread](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Relay-Response-not-getting-hit-SHA2-certificates-and-Authorize/m-p/35328#M19724) for more details.